# Find out the set(s) a list of parts belongs to?

Tags: piece-information

I have gotten some help here before regarding set identifications.  I now need to find the set some parts belong to.  I know how to find this per piece, but i need to search with a list instead.  Reason is that a part may belong to 100 sets, and another part may belong to 200 sets, together though may appear in a few sets.  This process would get much easier to a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use the rebrickable website for this:

- create a custom list (type to build)
- browse for the parts and add them to your custom list
- go to the custom list
- select Built this List
- go to the Suggested sets tab.

However, this amount of effort is normally not necessary to identify a set, there is nearly always a less common element in your list and bricklink can be used to list the sets having this element, narrow down manually with the second less common element, etc...

Comment: Per your suggestion, I did this.  After I click build this set, the suggested sets is 0.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please also note that I need ALL the pieces in the list to be part of the suggested set. Thanks

Comment: When selection "Build this List", there's a "Change build options" button, please make sure that you are not using lists of sets or parts you have entered previously, perhaps also experiment with the Build matching options or include/exclude options...

Comment: Also, if you would share your list, I'll happily try it for you...

Comment: No problem sharing the list.  But his function works partially correct.  I will explain.  This list (https://rebrickable.com/users/pavgoust/lists/22654/) contains 3 very distinct parts from set 8059.  When you ask to build the list it suggests 3 sets with 2 of the 3 parts but not the 8059 set.  Concluding, it is my opinion that this function is not perfect.

The list I am talking about is https://rebrickable.com/users/pavgoust/lists/22592/).

Let me know what do you think.  Thanks for your help and time devoted.

Comment: Agree that the first list should also show 8059, Perhaps the site prefers to show the other sets because they are cheaper/easier to find. As for your seccond list, I get the 60162 set suggested to complete about 80% and then the 60174 to complete to 100%. I think it might work a bit better if the lists contained a bit more elements.